# Whats the advantage of using a static NSString for CellIdentifier?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I always see boilerplate for `UITableViewController` declare

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier
```

in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Why static? I've changed this in a lot of places because my `CellIdentifier` changes based on the section? whats the reasoning behind this being static? Am I affecting performance?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath:` gets called *a lot*. Anytime you have a method that is called over and over in a short amount of time you want to minimize the number of objects that are waiting to be auto released, because these objects will be retained on the stack until -- at minimum -- the next run loop. Using a static string ensures that the string object only gets created once, rather than each time the method is called.

It's not strictly necessary, but when you have a limited amount of memory as you do on mobile devices, you want to optimize the number of objects that are created in a short amount of time, where possible.

Comment: So am I better off using a static NSString for each identifier?

Comment: Yes. Honestly, if you have a small number of rows in your table it won't really make much of a difference -- iOS has gotten much better at garbage collection, particularly since ARC came out. But even so, it's an optimization that takes no effort, so you might as well use it.

Comment: thanks this was more of a curiosity than a breaking issue but good to know moving forward. thanks.

Comment: While experienced developers will know what you mean, calling it "garbage collection" is confusing to newer developers. iOS does not have garbage collection. It has autorelease pools and ARC, which are implemented differently, and impose different trade-offs from garbage collectors.

Comment: This isn't garbage collection and improperly using the term just confuses users less familiar with Objective-C.

Comment: i understood. i am using arc. hes talking about auto-releasing and retain counts etc.

Comment: Yep. You guys are correct. Sorry -- my long lost .NET background is showing :D.

Comment: i use "garbage collection" inappropriately also, most ios people know i am talking about arc or autorelease.

Comment: Better to be correct though, and there are significant differences between a real GC and auto release pools. Anyway, updated the answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 3):

When a variable is declared `static`, there is only one instance of that variable in the program. Since this is a constant value that is only assigned one time, this approach avoids reserving and assigning a stack variable for it. Of course that stack variable is almost certainly optimized out by the compiler, and the string contant is already optimized into static storage by the compiler. So it's a pretty minor optimization that is as much a hint about what the developer means (i.e. all instances share the same value) as anything else.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with @Answerbot regarding the performance aspect of static strings, it's also worth noting that static strings are less error prone. The IDE will autocomplete the static NSString object, thus guaranteeing that the string is named consistently.

EDIT:

If you use the following code:

```
static NSString *cellIndentifier = @"myCellIdentifier";
```

you can then freely use the variable 'cellIdentifier' without worrying about the spelling of the actual string being used.

Comment: What do you mean by this? Xcode will autocomplete any variable name.

Comment: xcode autocompletes everything, regardless whether it is static, local or even a macro.

Comment: Yeah, what I meant was by stating static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier"; you can utilize XCode's autocomplete functions for the cellIdentifier variable instead of possibly screwing up and writing @"CellIdentifier" or @"cellidentifier" when you meant to say @"cellIdentifier"

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with the fact that it's `static`; it's just a reason to declare a variable instead of using the same literal string in multiple places.

Comment: Note: Lately I've taken to dropping static strings for cell identifier references. Now I typically do this: `NSString *cellIdentifier = NSStringFromClass([MyCustomCell class]);` this allows me to get design-time checking for the correct class rather than typing in a magic string.